# Anfangen/beginnen: transitiv oder intransitiv?

Tags: grammar

Während meines Sprachkurses in Deutschland wurde ich gelehrt, dass das Verb "anfangen" nur intransitiv oder mit der Präposition "mit" benutzt werden könne, aber laut dem Buch "Mastering German Vocabulary" ist "anfangen" auch transitiv. Gilt das nur als Umgangssprachlich? Wie ist es mit "beginnen"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*anfangen* als transitives Verb existiert und ist weitgehend gängig. Zum Beispiel:

> Ich habe das Spiel angefangen.
>
> Sie fängt das Rauchen an.

Laut [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anfangen) ist die transitive Verwendung mit Akkusativobjekt umgangssprachlich. Tatsächlich würde ich in formalem Kontext für die obigen Beispiele auch ein Präpositionalobjekt vorziehen:

> Ich habe mit dem Spiel anfangen.
>
> Sie fängt mit dem Rauchen an.

In dem Falle wäre *anfangen* intransitiv und zusammen mit der Präposition *mit* verwendet. In gesprochener Sprache ist die transitive Verwendung aber vollkommen akzeptabel und begegnet einem häufig.

Für *beginnen* gilt dasselbe wie für *anfangen*: Im Regelfall wird es intransitiv verwendet, eine transitive Verwendung in der Umgangssprache ist jedoch gängig.

Comment: *Beginnen* kann auch mit Akkusativobjekt *und* präpositionaler Erweiterung
verwendet werden (*"Er begann das Konzert mit einer Mozart-Sonate"*,
*"Er begann die Partie mit d2-d4"*). In diesen Fällen ist es gewöhnlich
nicht möglich, das Akkusativobjekt durch eine weitere präpositionale
Erweiterung zu ersetzen.

Comment: Das stimmt. In dem Falle würde ich auch einfach mal behaupten, dass es sich nicht bloß um umgangssprachlichen Gebrauch handelt, obwohl man *beginnen* natürlich auch durch Synonyme wie *eröffnen* ersetzen kann.